# Excel- Sum of two times to decides date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I creating a time line with duration as a key data. I start an activity at 10 am, duration is 60 minutes . I sum the start time and duration and it updates end time as 11:00 and date remains same.

lets say I start and activity at 23:30, duration is 60 minutes, end time is calculated as 00:30, now date should increment by 1 day.

Next iterations should continue same date until it reaches the 24 hour cycle to change the date automatically

Any help appreciated.

Comment: start an activity at 22:30, duration is 60 minutes, end time should be calculated as 23:30, not 00:30

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the following

```
     ¦  A  ¦   B    ¦  C  ¦
---------------------------
  1  ¦Start¦Duration¦ End ¦
     ¦     ¦ (mins) ¦     ¦
---------------------------
  2  ¦22:30¦  120   ¦     ¦
---------------------------
```

In cell `C2` enter the following:

```
=TIME(HOUR(A2),MINUTE(A2),SECOND(A2))+TIME(0,B2,0)
```

You will get `00:30`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**How it works:**

- Format Start time & Duration Column  with 
  `mm/dd/yy h:mm:ss AM/PM`.
- Act Time has `General` Format.

*Write this Formula in Cell `C2` & Fill down.*

```
=A2+(B2/24/60)
```

**N.B.**

- Since Excel `Date+Time` values are stored as a 
  floating point decimal number. So one hour is 
  essentially represented as `1 day/24 hours`.
- When you further divides it by `60`, you get 
  the representation of minutes,`1 day/24 hours/ 
  60 minutes`.